# React scripts not running onto devlopement environment -Openshift

Tags: openshift, package.json, react-scripts

I'm deploying my React, Node application onto openshift container platfrom.
I'm running the command concurrently at the backend. The backend runs perfectly with no issues. The frontend is causing the issues.

I'm running the command concurrently these are in package.json backend folder

```
"start": "node index.js",
"backend": "nodemon index.js",
"frontend": " npm run start --prefix ../frontend",
"frontendBuilt": "npm run built --prefix ../frontend",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend\" \"npm run frontendBuilt\" ",
```

I've tried the following none is working

```
"frontend": " npm  start --prefix /frontend",
"frontendBuilt": "npm  built --prefix /frontend",

"frontend": " npm start --prefix ../frontend",
"frontendBuilt": "npm built --prefix ../frontend",
```

Following is the log text

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.7
3 info using node@v12.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~predev: changemaker@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: changemaker@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/backend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /backend
10 silly lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'concurrently "npm run backend" "npm run frontend" ' ]
11 silly lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle changemaker@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: changemaker@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run backend" "npm run frontend" `
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
14 verbose pkgid changemaker@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /backend
16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-147.3.1.el8_1.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.2.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.7
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error changemaker@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run backend" "npm run frontend" `
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the changemaker@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]


                           Starting the development server...
                    [1] 
                    [1] The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
                    [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                    [1] npm ERR! errno 1
                    [1] npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
                    [1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
                    [1] npm ERR! 
                    [1] npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
                    [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
                    [1] 
                    [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                    [1] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-13T07_34_21_726Z-debug.log
                    [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                    [1] npm ERR! errno 1
                    npm ERR! changemaker@1.0.0 frontend: ` npm  start --prefix ../frontend`
                    [1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
                    [1] npm ERR! 
                    [1] npm ERR! Failed at the changemaker@1.0.0 frontend script.
                    [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
                    [1] 
                    [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                    [1] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-13T07_34_21_744Z-debug.log
                    [1] npm run frontend exited with code 1
```

if I run `npm run dev` at openshift container backend folder works perfectly without any issues

Can anyone let me know as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The react-scripts start command is a *dev* server, you shouldn't be running it in production. Build the frontend and either get the backend to serve it (as I have done here: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit) or deploy the static assets to a separate (e.g. Nginx) container (may require more complex networking and configuration).

Comment: @jonrsharpe please help me out I'm new I've no much idea onto it  should i use "build": "react-scripts build", would that do. the command is running concurrently in backend ,  "either get the backend to serve it" - have i understood correct?

Comment: That would create the files you need to somehow serve, yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "somehow serve" actually I don't want somehow but is that the good/best way I'm following(as I'm not aware) or there's much good which I'm not aware to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @jonrsharpe I'm serving the react from backend and deployed production build. A lil change in docker worked wonders. I've votes +1 to your comment